# Из милисекунд в Чч:Мм Дд/Мм/Гг?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здраствуйте, с back end`a приходит дата в милисекундах от 1970го...

Вопрос : Как мне показать на сайте эту дату в стандартном формате?

Comment: `var a = new Date(1516052901408);` так пытались ?

Comment: Да, спасибо)Может подскажете как вывести потом из переменной a - формат даты на примере: (21:32 28 сентябрь )!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Форматировать дату можно примерно так :

```js
var m = [
  'Января',
  'Февраля',
  'Марта',
  'Апреля',
  'Мая',
  'Июня',
  'Июля',
  'Августа',
  'Сентября',
  'Октября',
  'Ноября',
  'Декабря'
];

var a = new Date(1516052901408);
var b = ('00' + a.getHours()).slice(-2) + ':' + ('00' + a.getMinutes()).slice(-2) +
  ' ' + ('00' + a.getDate()).slice(-2) + ' ' + m[a.getMonth()];
console.log(b);
```

Comment: Огромнейшее спасибо)))

Comment: @VadymDoroshevych Не за что, но все же на данном ресурсе принято вместо слов благодарности просто принимать ответ проставив галочку слева вверху у ответа

Comment: Я сдеся новенький)Еще не адаптировался)

Answer (score 0):

Возможно этот плагин вам поможет:
https://github.com/phstc/jquery-dateFormat